# How to locate the crash site for a segfault in Net-SNMP agentX sub-agent

Tags: debugging, segmentation-fault, snmp

I am trying to understand a random segfault in agentX on Centos 64-bit. By random I mean the subagent is doing very little apart from checking if there is anything to do - the server it is a part of is idle and has been for a while. I have a stack trace that says the crash is at agentx_open_session+0x120. The version of Net-SNMP being used is what was obtained using yum and so it has no debugging symbols, but I know it is 5.5.41.el6_3.1.x86_64. I would like to know where to find debugging symbols for this version and how to use them to locate the crash site in the Net-SNMP code. I do not have a core file - just the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the CentOS Debuginfo repository for this.

Either [install the RPM directly](http://debuginfo.centos.org/6/x86_64/net-snmp-debuginfo-5.5-41.el6.x86_64.rpm) or, the preferred way, enable the repo by setting `enabled=1` in `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Debuginfo.repo`.

After that you're able to run a simple `yum install net-snmp-debuginfo`.

Then, to generate the core file, you need to enable core files for the user running net-smnpd. Unfortunately, for CentOS, this is the user `root`. So to enable core-files just for this session it's probably the best to add an `ulimit -c unlimited` to net-snmpd's startup-file `/etc/init.d/snmpd`. **Just for testing**. You really need to remove it later again.

Or, probably even better, shut down net-snmpd, start a root-shell, run `ulimit`, and start snmpd manually. If you can reproduce the problem reliably, this methode will spare you the cleaning up procedure.

Unfortunately I can't tell the location where it's going to dump core, but I'm sure you're going to find it.